# Why does an inline-block align to top if it has no content?

Tags: html, css

I have the [following simple setup](http://jsfiddle.net/kauto3n3/1/):

HTML

```
<input type=text>
<a></a>
<a>text</a>
<span></span>
<span>text</span>
```

CSS

```
input {
    width: 50px;
    height: 25px;
}

span, a {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 25px;
    background: green;
    color: white;
}

span {
       background: blue;
}
```

You can see that first anchor element and first span element is aligned to the top, while second anchor and span align on the same baseline as the input. Why so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The baseline of an inline-block that has no inline children, including text, is its bottom margin edge (or simply bottom edge if it has no bottom margin). This baseline is then aligned with the baselines of the rest of the text. This is mentioned at the very end of [section 10 of the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html).

Comment: @BoltClock, thanks a lot! Very clear and precise explanation. Is there any way to change this logic - _baseline is its bottom margin edge_ - by applying some css rule? Or basically two options only: either add content or tweak baselines of siblings?

Comment: @Maximus: One hacky workaround that comes to mind is adding a non-printed character, like a zero-width space, using `:before`. See http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/kauto3n3/4 Needs testing, though.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is vertically top aligned, only content is missing. If you use `<a>&nbsp;</a>`everything would be fine - [look here](http://jsfiddle.net/kauto3n3/3/). An empty inline tag has no baseline, so its bottom edge was used for alignment.

You have several solutions to align empty inline block tags:

- add `&nbsp;` (and they won't be empty anymore)
- as [BoltClock](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock)
  suggested, add an invisible character in `:before`
- change to vertical-align: bottom

Comment: bottom is not nearly the same thing as baseline. It really depends on the height of the elements.