# Why does putting text in an element push the element down?

Tags: html, css

Minimal example, just 2 divs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      div {
        display:inline-block;
        width:50px;
        height:50px;
        background-color:yellow;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div>whoa</div>
    <div></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

[Plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/DnyAOHJGNwy3jxrceBh3?p=preview)

[image]

What is the empty space above the first `div`? Why? How do I align them both to the top of the page, regardless if there is text in them?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/19366401/2680216

Comment: add `vertical-align:top;`

Comment: [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/b0a6ucEl4RASc3DGwM6e?p=preview)

Comment: Interestingly, this question is the polar opposite of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27293843/why-does-an-inline-block-align-to-top-if-it-has-no-content).